# Evaluate string to array

Tags: excel, vba

I am using such a line so as to assign the variable a to an array and it works well

```
a = [{"From","To";1,2;2.5,3.5;3.5,5;5.7,7}]
```

Now I have this stored in a string

```
    s = "[{""From"",""To"";1,2;2.5,3.5;3.5,5;5.7,7}]"
a = Evaluate(s)
```

How can I return the array from the string itself? I tried using Evaluate but this throws an error

```
Sub Test()
Dim a
Dim s As String

s = "[{""From"",""To"";1,2;2.5,3.5;3.5,5;5.7,7}]"
a = Evaluate(s)

'a = [{"From","To";1,2;2.5,3.5;3.5,5;5.7,7}]


Range("A1").Resize(UBound(a, 1), UBound(a, 2)).Value = a
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I could figure this out

```
    s = "[{""From"",""To"";1,2;2.5,3.5;3.5,5;5.7,7}]"
a = Evaluate(Replace(Replace(s, "[", ""), "]", ""))
```

But I welcome more ideas and suggestions.

Comment: to address more ideas and suggestions, please tell what of your solution is not satisfying you

Comment: The solution is OK. But I am not searching only for solutions. I am expecting more information that makes me learn. Have a nice day.

Comment: Not sure about it, so I'm just leaving this in comments: does `a = Evaluate(Mid(s, 2, Len(s) - 2))` bring you more informations and/or make you learn?

Comment: Thank you. This works too and simpler than using Replace more than once,